# Unpredictable behavior of SEARCH function with different errors

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I  have a problem with SEARCH function.
The same formula `=search(F1,PresenceDates)` works in one cells and does not in other producing different errors.

Here PresenceDates is a named range referring to another sheet, F1 is a date cell.

[not working here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYtCk.png)

[not working here with a different error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkmYV.png)

[same formula working here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E12Ao.png)

I coudn;t manage to find such behaviour recorded somewhere else

Comment: What happens when you press "Edit". If you can't upload more information here and we can help to edit the original question

Comment: @Martín it was asking to wait... now managed to do it, just don't know how to make the pics visible tho